# set <a href> item to the session object in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, javabeans, href

I have a jsp page which creates a list of links using variables. I want to pass the string representation of the link to a servlet.

```
<a href = "servletName">ItemToSetToSession</a>
```

I want to display **ItemToSetToSession** as the link and also set the string as an attribute in the session object.

Note: **ItemToSetToSession** is a variable which is displayed by a loop so it's not possible to use

```
session.setAttribute("item", ItemToSetToSession);
```

as each loop would set a different value but I want to just set the item which is clicked by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the `ItemToSetToSession` as a parameter to the servlet:

```
<a href = "servletName?item=ItemToSetToSession">ItemToSetToSession</a>
```

And inside the servlet code you can get this parameter like this

```
session.setAttribute("item",(String)request.getParameter("item"));
```